# Firebase .push() Error and ng-model not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Firebase .push failed: first argument contains undefined property 'price'
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('EditPicsController', function($scope,$location,$state) {

    var itemsRef = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/items');
    var itemprice = this.price
    $scope.createItem = function(itemprice){
        console.log(itemprice);
        var newItemRef = itemsRef.push({'price':itemprice});
    };  
});
```

And my template:

```
<form>
    <div class="list">
      <label ng-model="price" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Price</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="$200.00" >
      </label>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="createItem(price)" class='button button-dark'>
        test-additem
    </button>
</form>
```

my console.log output is blank.

What's going on here?

Comment: After you put `ng-model="price"` back onto the `input`, use `itemsRef.push({  price: $scope.price })` to pass it into Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply ng-model to `input` rather `label`.

```
<input ng-model="price" type="text" placeholder="$200.00" >
```

instead of

```
<label ng-model="price" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
```

And in your code you've created a `object` of a class i.e. `itemsRef`. Its an `object` not an `array`. So because of this line `itemsRef.push({'price':itemprice});` you're getting error. `push` is for `arrays` not for `object`.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I actually uploaded the wrong code. I only added ng-model to the label element because I was trying to figure out the error. I originally had it on the input element, and still got the same error.

Comment: You're right about `itemsRef` not pointing to an array. It instead points to a `Firebase` object, which defines a `push` method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to use angularJS in its entirety.

As mentioned in the other answer you should set ng-model on input element rather than label because then you can leverage the angularJS philosophy of two-way data binding.

This is because user can interact with your client-side application in angularJS and can only change the value of HTML elements which are editable.

So those values are ng-model and will be binded to your controller and exposed through the glue called $scope in your controller.

So your HTML will be:

```
<form>
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Price</span>
    <input ng-model="price" type="text" placeholder="$200.00" >
  </label>
</div>

<button ng-click="createItem()" class='button button-dark'>
    test-additem
</button>
```

And your controller code:

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('EditPicsController', function($scope,$location,$state) {

    $scope.itemsRef = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/items');
    $scope.createItem = function(){
        var newItemRef = $scope.itemsRef.push({'price': $scope.price});
    };  
});
```

Also if your `$scope.price` is undefined then Firebase will complain because it wont allow you to save values which are undefined so set some Form validation or initialise the ng-model (`$scope.price`) with some value to test.

**UPDATE: Your code `$scope.itemsRef.push({'price': $scope.price});` for saving to Firebase is absolutely correct its just that Firebase doesn't like undefined in javascript so your model $scope.price needs to have a value to get this working**

Answer (score 0):

Since Firebase does not like undefined attributes like this:

```
item = { 'name': 'hot dog', 'price': undefined };
itemsRef.push(item);
```

I do a quick and dirty clean up of my objects before I push

```
for( let attr in item){
    try {
        if( item[attr] == undefined ) delete item[attr];
    } catch(e){}
}
itemsRef.push(item);
```

which will push

```
{ 'name': 'hot dog' }
```

and firebase is happy :-) ..